# How can we upload images to the assets folder using angular

Tags: angular

How can we upload images to the assets folder in angular  from a form using the file upload input field from the front end .

```
<input type="file" >
```

Comment: what you try before..?

Comment: i need to upload  a file to folder using this tag in angular i have not tried any thing yet

Comment: share your code what you try before